# Tesseract text2image segmentation fault: 11

Tags: macos, ocr, tesseract, osx-elcapitan, text2image

In El capitan When i am apply text2image in tesseract training, the text2image give segmentation fault: 11 error.

I am applying this command: 
text2image --text=training_text.txt --outputbase=eng.TimesNewRomanBold.exp0 --font='Times New Roman Bold' --fonts_dir=/Library/Fonts

Answer (score 1):

For your specific error you can have a look here [here](http://ryanfb.github.io/etc/2014/11/19/installing_tesseract_training_tools_on_mac_os_x.html).
There is a version of tesseract that you can install through brew that fix this specific problem with text2image

As you can find on the link le command to run is

**brew install tesser --training-tools [--with-all-languages]**

However let me know if after that you'll get any other problem in your traning process because even if I sorted out "segmentation fail" I'm unable to complete successfully the training due another error that I'm not able to fix cuz very spare information around.
The error I get is about
**GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'PangoCairoCoreTextFont' to 'PangoFcFont'**

I've also tried to compile different source of tessercat but the above error still came out and (like you atm) I'm unable to start with the training process.